# Maximum repeated String in an array

Tags: java, arrays, max

The problem is

> how to get the maximum repeated String in an array using only operations on the arrays in java?

so i got into this question in a test and couldn't figure it out.
lets suppose we have an array of string.

```
str1[] = { "abbey", "bob", "caley", "caley", "zeeman", "abbey", "bob", "abbey" }
str2[] = { "abbey", "bob", "caley", "caley", "zeeman", "abbey", "bob", "abbey", "caley" }
```

1. in  `str1` *abbey* was maximum repeated, so *abbey* should be returned and
2. in `str2` *abbey* and *caley* both have same number of repetitions and hence we take maximum alphabet as the winner and is returned(*caley* here).

   c > a

so i tried till

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {
    static String highestRepeated(String[] str) {
        int n = str.length, num = 0;
        String temp;
        String str2[] = new String[n / 2];

        for (int k = 0;k < n; k++) {  // outer comparision
            for (int l = k + 1; l < n; l++) { // inner comparision
                if (str[k].equals(str[l])) {
                    // if matched, increase count
                    num++;
                }
            }
             // I'm stuck here
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter how many votes");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String[] str = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Str[i] = sc.nextLine();

        }
        String res = highestRepeated(str);
        System.out.println(res + " is the winner");
    }
}
```

so, how should i take the count of occurrence of each string with and attach it with the string itself.

All this, without using a map and any hashing but just by using arrays?

Comment: you could use hasmap

Comment: no....we shouldn't use map...and it should be made only using array opeartions @ShanuGupta

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This is about arrays, not array lists. None of the answers of the dupe target actually satisfies the constraints of this post.

Comment: @nikhil2000 Are you allowed `sort`?

Comment: any functions that can be applied on arrays.@Sweeper

Comment: Can you use arraylist?

Comment: no, only arrays..@user3437460

Comment: @sweeper..it works...but the ""Comparator.reverseOrder()"" didn't work fine.

Comment: is it needed to import collections for comparator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a (unpolished) solution:

```
static String highestRepeated(String[] str) {
    String[] sorted = Arrays.copyOf(str, str.length);
    Arrays.sort(sorted, 0, sorted.length, Comparator.reverseOrder());
    String currentString = sorted[0];
    String bestString = sorted[0];
    int maxCount = 1;
    int currentCount = 1;
    for (int i = 1 ; i < sorted.length ; i++) {
        if (currentString.equals(sorted[i])) {
            currentCount++;
        } else {
            if (maxCount < currentCount) {
                maxCount = currentCount;
                bestString = currentString;
            }
            currentString = sorted[i];
            currentCount = 1;
        }
    }
    if (currentCount > maxCount) {
        return currentString;
    }
    return bestString;
}
```

Explanation:

Sort the array from highest to lowest lexicographically. That's what `Arrays.sort(sorted, 0, sorted.length, Comparator.reverseOrder());` does. we sort in this order because you want the largest string if there are multiple strings with the same number of repeats.

Now we can just count the strings by looping through the array. We don't need a hash map or anything because we know that there will be no more of a string in the rest of the array when we encounter a different string.

`currentString` is the string that we are currently counting the number of repeats of, using `currentCount`. `maxCount` is the number of occurrence of the most repeated string - `bestString` - that we have currently counted.

The if statement is pretty self-explanatory: if it is the same string, count it, otherwise see if the previous string we counted (`currentCount`) appears more times than the current max.

At the end, I check if the last string being counted is more than max. If the last string in the array happens to be the most repeated one, `bestString` won't be assigned to it because `bestString` is only assigned when a *different* string is encountered.

Note that this algorithm does not handle edge cases like empty arrays or only one element arrays. I'm sure you will figure that out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

another version

```
static String lastMostFrequent(String ... strs) {
    if (strs.length == 0) return null;
    Arrays.sort(strs);
    String str = strs[0];
    for (int longest=0, l=1, i=1; i<strs.length; i++) {
        if (!strs[i-1].equals(strs[i])) { l=1; continue; }
        if (++l < longest) continue;
        longest = l;
        str = strs[i];
    }
    return str;
}
```

change in

```
if (++l <= longest) continue;
```

for firstMostFrequent

Answer (score -1):

you can't use == to check if two strings are the same.
try using this instead:

```
if (str[k].equals(str[l])) {
                // if matched, increase count
                num++;
            }
```

Comment: yeah...that's also a different problem..i will change it.

Comment: but it is more concerned about the occurences and returning the string with maximum alphabet of first letter.